# JPA Batch update not working with native sql query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, batch-processing

I am using jpa/hibernate in my application and have enabled jdbc batching:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100

however there are some sections in the code which still use Native sqls to update the DB and I noticed that batch update/insert is not working for those native queries

```
EntityManager em;
em.flushMode(FlushModeType.Commit);
em.beginTransaction();
for (i ....){
//some business logic
  em.createNativeQuery("update some db row"); //Batch:False (not updated in batch)
}
em.commit();
```

basically the update method is called from multiple places, and idea is that all the records should be persisted in batch at the end of transaction.

I think this is happening because with native query we are bypassing first level catche and writing to the db directly, however Is there any way we can leverage jpa batching with native query?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with a native SQL. JPA providers cannot order native sql and are required to execute them immediately when you call execute on the query - so they can't be delayed and batched up when the transaction commits. If you want batch processing, you'll have to use JPA managed entity objects or control the statements yourself (JDBC)

Answer (score 0):

If your update is working but not in batches, then you should probably try after setting the property **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates** to true. This ensures that Hibernate executes all identical update statements that only differ in the provided bind parameter values. Without this property, the JDBC driver closes and executes the batch when you execute a different DB update elsewhere. By ordering the statements, you enable the JDBC driver to group the updates as efficiently as possible.

If update call isn't working in the first place, then check out the solutions provided here: https://thorben-janssen.com/use-native-queries-perform-bulk-updates/

Comment: That is a native query for a bulk update, which happens to work the same as JPQL bulk insert/update/delete operations - they bypass the cache and are executed immediately. It doesn't touch on batching multiple bulk update statements - and it cannot, as when you call execute on the query it has to return the absolute number of rows affected, so it cannot delay and batch up multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have another question as well related to bulk ordered update, Could provide any help here as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643543/enable-ordered-update-insert-for-a-specific-workflow