# enable ordered update/insert for a specific workflow

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, batch-processing

I am using jpa/hibernate in my application and working on adding a new workflow. Now I want to enable jdbc batching only for a new workflow rather than enabling it for the entire application.

I am able to achieve it by enabling jdbc batching on entitymanager for a new workflow.

```
EntityManager em;
em.beginTransaction(); 
em.flushMode(FlushModeType.Commit);
em.unwrap(sessionImpl.class).setJdbcBatchSize(100);
```

**however I am not sure how to enable ordered insert and update only for this specific workflow (do not want to add it in application.properties)? Is there any way to achieve this?**

**Also, wanted to check if is it true that ordered update/insert makes the overall bulk insert/update process slow?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a session factory wide configuration and can only be enabled for the whole application.